# Forecasting based on MAD or MAPE

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm a student learning forecast, a beginner in R.

I'm forecasting a seasonal data using HoltWinter, however, i want to R optimize alpha, beta and gamma based on a different criteria rather than only MSE, (maybe MAD or MAPE).

1) There is a way `HoltWinters()` or `hw()` can do this by themselves?

2) Even better, there is a way R can optimize the parameters based on a diferent function or equation that i can choose?

Comment: Use the `ets` function from the forecast package, and check out the `opt.crit` argument.

Comment: Thanks @RobHyndman , There is a way i can choose MAPE as a criteria? i dont see it in `opt.crit`

Comment: No, that is not one of the options provided. Minimizing MAPE makes little sense statistically. See Gneiting (JASA, 2011).